# yaml azure devops CI | if condition not work

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

[image]

that my if condition and inside I have task, and once build from dev branch running is Still running and not skip on the task.

what wrong with that if condition?

EDIT:

my condition are not working:

```
- ${{ if or(ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/dev') , ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/main')) }}:
```

Comment: Can you share more YAML code sample of this issue? It will be helpful to check this issue

Comment: What is the exact name of the branch ?

Comment: this is the name of branch : dev

Comment: please paste more of your yaml in a code block, so we can help you better and the text is searchable

Comment: - ${{ if or(ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/dev') , ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/main')) }}:      |||||            that my if condition and is not works , I want to filter it to get inside the if only from dev branch or main branch..

Comment: @vfdsabvdasvd Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answers can help you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is your branch exact `dev` or more like `dev/*`.
The if condition now expects exactly `dev`.

Try something like this example:

```
not(containsValue(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], ‘dev’ ))
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#containsvalue

Comment: - ${{ if or(not(containsValue(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], ‘dev’ )) , not(containsValue(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], main )) }}:

Comment: is wrong syntx, you know why?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter it to get inside the if only from dev branch or main branch..

From your YAML sample to set the if expression, you need to change the operator from `or` to `and`.

```
steps:
- ${{ if and(ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') , ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main')) }}: 
  - script: env | sort
```

When you use the `and` operator, the task will only run if the source branch name is not `dev` and `master`.

When you use the `or` operator, one of the two conditions needs to be met to run the task. When branch is dev, it satisfies `ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'` so task will run.

Comment: Ok, so now if there is a build from the dev branch, will it go into IF?
(same for main)

I wrote or in the condition because I thought I was defining either build from main or build from dev.

And when you write in the condition 'and' it means that you need both conditions to enter the condition, doesn't it?

Comment: When a build from the dev branch, it will go into IF and the result is **NO**, it will skip the target task. When we set and in IF expression, it means that it will run the task when the branch is not equal main and dev branch.